# When i add this thing in my onCreate method why my app is unfortunately stopped

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

when i add this thing in my oncreate method why my app is unfortunately stopped

ListView mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

```
    ArrayList<String> myfamily = new ArrayList<String>();
    myfamily.add("PAPA");
    myfamily.add("BHAI");
    myfamily.add("MUMMA");
    myfamily.add("ME");
```

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myfamily);

```
    mylistview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: share your crash log

Comment: Provide the stacktrace which will show where it crashed. I would think though the likely culprit is your mylistview is null when you set the adaper. Have you done `myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.string.mylistview)` to set your list view object from your layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're initialising your lsitview in onCreateView and setting it in onCreate which won't work as onCreate will be called first.